# Python Pickle Issue

Tags: python, pickle

We had given a task and for which we written below code, while executing it showing an error. Hence issue in pickle need help for . Please let us know where we went wrong in coding-

```
import os
import builtins
import pickle
import sys
sys.tracebacklimit=0
import traceback
import io
from logging import Logger

safe_builtins = {
        'range',
        'complex',
        'set',
        'frozenset',
        }

class RestrictedUnpickler(pickle.Unpickler):

      def find_class(self, module, name):
      # Only allow safe classes from builtins.
       if module == "builtins" and name in safe_builtins:
           return getattr(builtins, name)
        # Forbid everything else.
       raise pickle.UnpicklingError("global '%s.%s' is forbidden" %
       (module, name))
    
    def restricted_loads(s):
        """Helper function analogous to pickle.loads()."""
        return RestrictedUnpickler(io.BytesIO(s)).load()
    
    def func1(a): 
      try: 
        x= restricted_loads(pickle.dumps(a))
          return x 
            except pickle.UnpicklingError : 
      s=traceback.format_exc()
         return s
    
    
    def func2(s):
      try:
        x=restricted_loads(pickle.dumps(s))
        return s[x]
      except pickle.UnpicklingError :
 s=traceback.format_exc()
        return s
    
       
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        a=range(int(input())) 
        b=func1(a)
        print(b)
        y=tuple(input())
        z=func2(y)
        print(z)
```

Getting, we assume issue is with function 2. Where we are not getting correct output. Function 1 is working perfectly seems that why we are getting some output. We had also attach a image for problem statement i.e. what we need to perform in the different function.

Please suggest where we went wrong.

```
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Input (stdin)
50 
"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"

Your Output (stdout) 
range(0, 50)

Expected Output 
range(0, 50) 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
_pickle.UnpicklingError: global 'builtins.slice' is forbidden
```

[image: Problem Statement]

Comment: Why are you (A): importing `builtins` yourself, and (B): making only some properties of it usable? Plus, it might help if you add `slice` to the list of permitted functions in `builtins`.

Comment: Okay, try printing out what `restricted_loads(pickle.dumps(s))` is returning, i.e. `print(x)` on the line below. That might shed more light on the second problem.

Comment: There is no issue with fun1.. main issue is with func2 look like

Comment: we tried to print x.....x = ('"', 'a', '"', ',', ' ', '"', 'b', '"', ',', ' ', '"', 'c', '"', ',', ' ', '"', 'd', '"', ',', ' ', '"', 'e', '"', ',', ' ', '"', 'f', '"', ',', ' ', '"', 'g', '"', ',', ' ', '"', 'h', '"')
an example

Comment: In another input we have      ,,,,,                ('1', ',', '2', ',', '3', ',', '4', ',', '5')

Comment: we had tried `    x = slice(a[0:8:3])
    print(x)
    return s[x]`

Comment: TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method

Comment: range(0, 50)
slice(None, range(0, 8, 3), None)

Comment: we did x = slice(0, 8, 3) then there is no error but required output not coming

Comment: ```
def func2(s):
    try:
        x= slice(0, 8, 3)
        return s[x]
    except pickle.UnpicklingError :
        s=traceback.format_exc()
        return s
```

Comment: Your Output (stdout)
range(0, 50)
('"', ',', 'b')

Comment: Expected Output
range(0, 50)
Traceback (most recent call last):
_pickle.UnpicklingError: global 'builtins.slice' is forbidden

Comment: any issue with def find_class(self, module, name):

Comment: Issue resolved....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#frescoplay pickle problem 
import os
import builtins
import pickle
import sys
sys.tracebacklimit=0
import traceback
import io
from logging import Logger

safe_builtins = {
        'range',
        'complex',
        'set',
        'frozenset',
        }

class RestrictedUnpickler(pickle.Unpickler):

   def find_class(self, module, name):
    # Only allow safe classes from builtins.
      if module == "builtins" and name in safe_builtins:
          return getattr(builtins, name)
    # Forbid everything else.
      raise pickle.UnpicklingError("global '%s.%s' is forbidden" %
      (module, name))
        
        

def restricted_loads(s):
        """Helper function analogous to pickle.loads()."""
        return RestrictedUnpickler(io.BytesIO(s)).load()

def func1(a): 
    try: 
        x= restricted_loads(pickle.dumps(a))
        return x 
    except pickle.UnpicklingError : 
        s=traceback.format_exc()
        return s
    
    
def func2(s):
    try:
        x=restricted_loads(pickle.dumps(slice(s)))
        return s[x]
    except pickle.UnpicklingError :
        s=traceback.format_exc()
        return s

    
if __name__ == "__main__":
       a=range(int(input`enter code here`())) 
       b=func1(a)
       print(b)
       y=tuple(input())
       z=func2(y)
       print(z)
```

Answer (score 1):

In the func2, write
x=restricted_loads(pickle.dumps(slice(s)))